# Ubuntu: Getting sudo access as guest

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, guest-account

I installed Ubuntu Linux 12.04 a little while ago to try it out and play around with it (hence I have no idea what I'm doing). I tried changing my home directory by editing the `/etc/passwd` file, however I must have put in a bad value as I can no longer login to my account. Whenever I try it boots me out to the login screen before I can make it to the desktop. The only other account is guest (I hadn't gotten around to disabling it yet), and I can login to that just fine.

Since I know which file I screwed up, I can edit it back to what it was and hopefully login again. However, since this is a system file, it requires `sudo` access to modify, which I don't have as a guest. Is there any workaround where I can somehow get `sudo` access as guest so I can edit this file and login as myself again? Obviously I don't intend to leave that ability on guest, that would be silly.

I remember reading somewhere that I could ssh to localhost as a user with `sudo` privileges, however I keep getting "connection refused". I believe it needs to be installed, and I hadn't gotten to that, and I can't do it now without `sudo` anyways...

I did install Linux alongside Windows 7, so if there's some way to edit it via Windows, I could do that (though from my understanding Windows can't read the file system).

Comment: Are there any other users on the system with sudo or root rights? Alternatively, can you boot in single user mode to fix it ?

Comment: Oh wow, I was able to [boot into single user mode](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grub-boot-into-single-user-mode/) (never heard of that before) and got root access. I just did `vi /etc/passwd` and changed the file back to what it should be. Restarted and could login. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Another nice command to lean is `vipw` (It does sanity checks, preventing some typos from locking you or any other user out).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) or append `init=/bin/bash` to your boot entry to login to a root shell

Answer (score 2):

ctrl+alt+F1 and start TTY > login with your account and use sudo privileges

[here is one example](http://www.stuckngo.com/2014/11/how-to-run-sudo-command-from-guest.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from the live-cd and chroot into your installation and then change the password.  Instructions to do so can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/).